# Sieve of Eratosthenes Issue Java

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've got an issue with an assignment that I have requiring the use of arrays. I need to create the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm and print out all the prime numbers. I'm quite confused because as far as I can tell, my order of operations is correct. Here is the code:

```
        //Declare the array
        boolean numbers [] = new boolean[1000];
        int y = 0;

        //Declare all numbers as true to begin
        for(int i = 2; i < 1000;i++){
            numbers[i] = true;
        }
        //Run loop that increases i and multiplies it by increasing multiples
        for (int x = 2; x < 1000; x++) {

            //A loop for the increasing multiples; keep those numbers below 1000
            //Set any multiple of "x" to false
            for(int n = 2; y < 1000; n++){
            y = n * x;
            numbers[y] = false;
            }
        }
```

I first set all the numbers in the array to true. Then the second loop will start "x" at 2,  then inside it is a nested loop that will multiply "x" by values of "n" and "n" will continue to increase as long as the product of that multiplication ("y") is below 1000. Once "y" reaches that maximum, "x" will go up one number and the process repeats until all non-prime numbers are set to false.

That was my logic when I made the code, but when I try to run it I get the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error. From what I can tell I set everything to stay below 1000 so it shouldn't be going over the array size.

I know its probably not the most efficient algorithm because as "x" increases it will go over numbers it already went over but it was the most simple one I could think of.

Comment: Take a look at your indexing of variable `y`, which could easily have a value well over 1000.

Comment: In addition, your inner-for loop is testing against x instead of n, meaning that n will never be bound and will continue infinitely in the inner loop causing an array out of bounds even if the y issue mentioned above was not present.

Comment: Sorry, the nested loop was supposed to say y < 1000 not sure how it got changed to x. Edited it

Comment: Elegant java implementation of Sieve http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
        for(int n = 2; y < 1000; n++){
        y = n * x;
        numbers[y] = false;
        }
```

you *first* check that `y < 1000`, and *then* intialize and use it. This is the wrong way around.

Also, you can get away with running the above loop only when `x` is prime. This won't affect correctness, but should make your code much faster.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I added an `if(y < 1000)` then `numbers[y] = false;` Thanks a bunch